# UI objects create instance when they are linked to swift file?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to Swift. 
In the below code, text is instance property? and so It needs an instance before it's used?
when they are linked to swift file from storyboard, UI objects automatically create an instance?
I don't see  instance creating code but it works well.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var zxcaa: UILabel!

    zxcaa.text = "hello"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.text is instance property and so It needs instance before it's used?**

UILabel is a class, zxcaa is its instance, and text is the stored property. To access a stored property, you need to create an instance.

**2.UI objects create instance? when they are linked to swift file from storyboard?**

yes.